# Type alias 'RootStateType' circularly references itself in Redux store

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, types

Why am I having following errors and how to fix them?

'store' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.ts(7022)

Type alias 'RootStateType' circularly references itself.ts(2456)

Code and errors screenshots:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVV1u.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHAv3.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1XX4.png